# How can I disable a UITabBar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

How can I disable the tab bar of a UITabBarController? I want to disable the UITabBar and enable it after clicking a button.

Answer (score 8):

```
UITabbarcontroller.tabbar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Good answer, but (tabBar) is case sensitive, so the command should be: self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 3):

You could also set your UITabBarControllerDelegate to return NO for the following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```